# Update a varchar column depending of the actual value

Tags: postgresql, function, sql-update

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

I have a `varchar` column in a table that can be null and I want to update it depending of its value is null or not.

I didn't manage to do a function that takes a String as argument and updates the value like this:
If the column is null, the function concatenates the current string value, a comma and the string given as argument, else it just adds the string at the end of the current string value (without comma).

**So how can I make a different Update depending of the column value to update?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement to conditionally update a column:

```
update the_table
  set the_colum = case 
                    when the column is null then 'foobar'
                    else the_column||', '||'foobar'
                  end
```

Answer (score 1):

An another approach

```
 UPDATE foo
 SET bar = COALESCE(NULLIF(concat_ws(', ', NULLIF(bar, ''), NULLIF('a_string', '')), ''), 'a_string')
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you know if this approach gives better performance results?

Comment: @user3683807 Need a Test :) for that, It depends the Data